# Resultado de um comando em uma variável

Tags: c, variáveis, bash

Quando executo o seguinte código ele armazena o status de saída do comando `wc  -l` que tem valor 0, pois foi executado com sucesso.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {

    int status = system("echo 'hello world' | wc -l");
    printf("%d", status);

    return 0;
}
```

Mas o que preciso é do valor do resultado desse comando, que nesse caso veio a ser 1. Como faço para armazenar esse resultado em uma variável em C??

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `popen()` que invoca o *shell* e retorna uma estrutura de tipo `FILE*`. Para isto basta especificar o comando e o tipo que é para leitura `"r"` neste caso.

Um exemplo ilustrativo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp;
    int status;
    char conteudo[200]; //define o tamanho do buffer aqui

    fp = popen("echo \"Hello Word\" | wc -l", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; //Manipule os erros
    }

    while (fgets(conteudo, 200, fp) != NULL) 
        printf("%s\n", conteudo);

    status = pclose(fp);
    if (status == -1) {
        printf("Error\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE; //Manipule os erros
    }
    else {
        //aqui pode determinar se houve sucesso ou uma falha na execucao do comando.
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Saída:

> 1

Mais informações sobre a [função popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/popen.html), ou consulte o manual digitando `man popen` no terminal.

Comment: isso me ajuda muito! Mas ainda tenho uma dúvida... como faço para isolar esse código numa função que receba uma string de um comando e retorne um resultado?